# How to make option in select menu point to Django URL

Tags: javascript, django

I have this view as context_processors.py which means I can present an archive as a drop - down menu in a select html tag.

```
def blogposts_processor(request):
    blogposts = BlogPost.objects.all()
    q=blogposts.dates('date', 'month')
    s = [(i.strftime('%b'),i.strftime('%Y')) for i in q]

    return {'blogposts': blogposts,'s':s}
```

I have already present the dates like Feb 2018, Apr 2018 etc:

```
 <script>   
    var n =[{% for i in q %}"{{ i|safe }}"{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}];

    var k=[];

    var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

    var dynamicSelect = document.getElementById("selectdate");

    n.forEach(function(entry){
        a = new Date(entry);

        amonth=  months[a.getMonth()];
        ayear = a.getFullYear();
        c = amonth + " " + ayear;
        k.push(c);


        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.text = c;
        dynamicSelect.add(newOption);
</script>
```

Now my url for archive is

```
 url(r'^(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[-\w]+)/$',
    BlogPostMonthArchiveView.as_view(),
    name="blogpost_month_archive"),
```

I want each option in the select drop down menu to link to the correct archive. So each option in the menu should have URL

```
 {% url 'home:blogpost_month_archive' year='ayear' month='amonth' %}
```

I have made a start and looked for solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311042/call-django-urls-inside-javascript-on-click-event)

```
   var url = "{% url 'home:blogpost_month_archive' year='2018' month='Feb' %}"
   var year = $(this).attr('ayear');
   var month = $(this).attr('amonth');
   document.location.href = url.replace('2018', year).replace('Feb', month);
```

I'm not too far away, I just don't know how to attach the document.location.href bit to the options element.

I am looking for JavaScript solution only please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just used

```
var year = $(this).val().slice(4,8);
var month = $(this).val().slice(0,3);
```

So final code look like :

```
<script>    
    var n =[{% for i in q %}"{{ i|safe }}"{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}];

    var k=[];

    var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

    var dynamicSelect = document.getElementById("selectdate");

    n.forEach(function myFunc(entry){
        a = new Date(entry);

        var amonth = months[a.getMonth()];
        var ayear = a.getFullYear();

        c = amonth + " " + ayear;
        k.push(c);

        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.text = c;
        dynamicSelect.add(newOption);


        document.getElementById("selectdate").onclick=function(){

            var url  = "{% url 'home:blogpost_month_archive' year=2018 month='Feb' %}";
            var year = $(this).val().slice(4,8);
            var month = $(this).val().slice(0,3);
            document.location.href = url.replace('2018', year).replace('Feb', month);

        }

        });



</script>
```

I was trying to retrieve the variables, amonth and ayear from myFunc and then use the in the onclick function but I didn't manage to get it to work. So this is the next best working solution I had.