# How can I pass the text which I clicked on href link from one age to another page in JS and that should be usable in django code?

Tags: javascript, html, django, python-django-storages

This is the code written in Django. When I click the link on the displayed results of links, the text,link of href (for example Redmi Note 5 rendered in {{post.0}} in the below code)should be saved and pass that text{{pass.0}} and link{{pass.1}} to another page to get the same text and it is used as the title. How can I do it?

Page1.html

```
{% for post in product_names %}
    <a href="{{ post.1 }}" onclick="savefunc({{post.1}},{{post.0}})">{{ post.0 }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Page2.html

```
 <h1 id="h1_title"style="text-align:center;background:linear-gradient(to right,rgb(166, 204, 255),rgb(15, 242, 216));margin-left:2%;margin-right:2%;box-shadow:1px 5px 5px 1px rgb(90,150,100,210);padding:30px;font-weight:bold;">[ Here I want to get that text from page1.html ]</h2>
```

Suggestions in both JS or in Django is accepted. Please help me.

Comment: This is what you are actually looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/37311391/14152356

Comment: no bro that's not right. I'm looking answers to the question " when I click on the anchor tag text then the text and href should be passed to the view. So How can I write in my views app or in urls.py