# Injecting js variable in django url

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-urls

My url looks like this :

```
path('tree_sensor\/(?P<sensorID>.*)', views.tree_sensor, name='tree_sensor')
```

and i have a `var sID = 1,2,etc` which i want to inject into a django url in a button

```
<a class='popup_button small_text' href='{% url 'agriculture:tree_sensor' "sID" %}'><span>Sensor Page</span></a>")
```

template:

```
for (i in motePos) {
    markers.addLayer(mote[i].on('click', function(e) {
        var sID = this.id;
       
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : "{% url 'agriculture:sensor_ms' %}",
            data : {"sID" : sID},
            success: function(response){
               
                var measurement = JSON.parse(response["measurement"]);
                var fields = measurement[0]["fields"];
                console.log(sID)
                mote[i].bindPopup("<h3>Tree Sensor: " + motePosName[i] + "</h3>" 
               "<br><a class='popup_button small_text' href='{% url 'agriculture:tree_sensor' sID %}'><span>Sensor Page</span></a>").openPopup();
                mote[i].name = motePosName[i];
                mote[i].id = motePosId[i];     
            }
        })
    }));
```

Current url prints "tree_sensor/sID" . I want to get the ID from the objects so it would be something like "tree_sensor/1" "tree_sensor/2" etc.

Comment: Can you include more of your template? I guess you are using a for loop (`for sensor in sensors`) to assign all links? If so, you can simply do `{% url 'agriculture:tree_sensor' sensor.pk %}`

Comment: I've changed it take a look plz

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37311391/17851130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DrummerMann suggested it works out like this :

```
var sensorID = "href='{% url 'agriculture:tree_sensor' 12345 %}'";
var url_mask = sensorID.replace("12345", fields["sensor"]);
```

and the button to the link

```
"<br><a class='popup_button small_text' "+url_mask+" ><span>Sensor Page</span></a>"
```