# How to pass an object's id to a js function outside of a for ? DJANGO

Tags: javascript, django

I have a delete button that deletes an object from the database. This button has a js windows.confirm function for deletion. I need to pass servico.id to function so I can reference the object in the view. How do I do this?

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return myFunction()">Delete</a>
```

Script

```
        <script>
          function myFunction() {
            if (window.confirm("Você tem certeza que deseja excluir ?")) {
              window.location.href="{% url 'servico:excluir-servico' servico.id  %}";            
            }
          }
        </script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call django urls inside javascript on click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311042/call-django-urls-inside-javascript-on-click-event)

Comment: I got it, but it happens that it takes the first data-url and doesn't change anymore

Answer (score 0):

html

```
   <a href="#" data-id="{{servico.id}}" id="de" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return myFunction()">Delete</a>
```

js

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
     if (window.confirm("Você tem certeza que deseja excluir ?")) {
      _id = $('#').attr(''data-id)
      window.location.href="`${window.location.pathname}/${_id}`;";            
    }
   }
</script>
```

I used jquery you need to include it.